# What's the value of b?

Tags: trigonometry

The function, $\cos(bx)=\sin(2x)+1$, only has solution at $0$. What's the value of $b$?

I'm not sure about this question. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem? Offhand, I have to call shenanigans.

Comment: Are you sure you've correctly stated the question?

Comment: If you write your equation with $\displaystyle{\large\cos\left(\mu x\right) = {z^{2\mu} + 1 \over 2z^{\mu}}, \mbox{where}\ z \equiv {\rm e}^{{\rm i}x}}$, you get a polynomial. Then, you can use any thing you know about poly's.

Comment: There is no problem with $\large b$.
$\displaystyle{\large b = {\arccos\left(\sin\left(2x\right) + 1\right) + 2n\pi \over x}\,,\quad n\ \in\ {\mathbb Z}}$.

Answer (score 1):

At $x\neq 0$, then

$b = \frac{-cos^{-1}(sin(2x)+1)-2\pi n}{x} $ negative b

or

$b = \frac{2 \pi n + cos^{-1}(sin(2x)+1)}{x} $ positive b